# How to print certain amount of numbers in one line and then again in other?

Tags: python, loops, numbers, range

Im looking for an output that will print numbers from 100 to 200 with 15 numbers in one line

100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115

116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130,
131

.....

what i have right now is this:

```
for number in range(100,200):
   print(number, end = ", ")
```

what do i need to add ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` to get the number position, then use condition  to whether print a comma or go nextline

```
per_line = 15
for idx, number in enumerate(range(100, 200), 1):
    if idx % per_line != 0:
        print(number, end=", ")
    else:
        print(number)
```

Can be inlined in

```
for idx, number in enumerate(range(100, 200), 1):
    print(number, end=", " if idx % per_line != 0 else "\n")
```

Comment: This works but if i set "per_line" to more then 11 it doesnt work anymore. Im trying to do the same thing but between the number 100 and 200 with 15 number in one line.

Comment: @bbombos fixed, That was unclear that you would use range not starting at 1

Answer (score 0):

There are many variants for that. I would do so

```
for i, number in enumerate(range(1,11),1):
   print(number, end=(", " if i%5 else '\n'))
```